# How to activate owner-approval on self-service group membership?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a security group in Azure AD and am the owner of that group with P2 license. In the self service group portal I can switch between users can join that group or owner hat to manage membership. But how can I setup that unseres can request to join and the owner needs to approve? I don’t find anything in the docs about that. If I try to add myself via the self service portal I get the feedback that it was auto-approved. But how to change the config, that I need to approve before?

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I setup **Self Service Group Management** in the Azure Portal like below:

[image]

I created a test group **`securitygroup`** and when the user requested to join the group from the [**Access Panel**](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/joinGroups), the request got **auto approved** like below:

[image]

**The user was added in the group successfully like below:**

[image]

> **How can I setup that users can request to join and the owner needs to approve**

*Login to Access Panel as Global Admin -> Groups -> Select the Group you want to set membership -> Edit Details -> Select This group requires owner approval*

[image]

After the above settings the user will get the user will get the pop-up like below:

[image]

Once the **owner of the group approves the request** the user will be added to the group successfully.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Set up self-service group management - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-self-service-management#self-service-group-membership)